# IBM Worklight - How to push "Disable state event" to the app from the server?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

When I deploy and use application from Worklight server (Hosted on Apache Tomcat) everything works fine.

Now, When I make the Application State Disabled from Server. I want the client to be notified the same moment. Currently I am getting notified when my client application takes some action. How do I accomplish direct push from server when state is changed from Enable to Disable?

Any Reference guide for That?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ability, or feature, does not exist in Worklight.
IMO it is not needed. Read the below.

Note the actual meaning of Remote Disable: "Remote Disable" is not about *disabling the app itself*, but rather about *preventing the app from connecting to the Worklight Server* (fetch data, ...).

That is the default behavior. Once an app is "disabled", the app itself is functional, but any request to the server will be blocked. So there is nothing to "push" to the app...

User documentation:

- [Remotely disabling application connectivity](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.appadmin.doc/admin/t_denying_access_to_older_app_versions.html)

If what you want is to *disable the app itself*, you will need to override the default  behavior. You can accomplish this by updating the app with custom behavior. This way, the next time the app tries to connect to the Worklight Server once it has been disabled, it will be blocked completely - this will depend on how and what you will implement. For example, display another HTML all together.

Blog post:

- [How to create a customized remote disable behavior](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/how_to_create_a_customized_remote_disable_behavior?lang=en)

Comment: Same Applies for Disabling specific Device?

Comment: The above is regarding the Remote Disable feature; remote disable is about blocking access to the server from a specific app version (for example, Android environment with version 2.5). It is not about a specific user (device). Revoking access from a device will be just that - revoking. The next time that device tries to connect it will be blocked as well, but I do not believe it has a custom screen like remote disable.